# Indirect object pronoun before direct object

Tags: direct-objects, indirect-objects, prepositional-objects, argument-structure, dative-alternation

I have seen a few people say that indirect objects that are in the form of a pronoun should be placed before the direct object in a sentence. Why is that? I didn’t know it mattered. For example:

“I gave him the movie while you were gone”
Versus
“I gave the movie to him while you were gone”

And any similar, better examples.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct and present an indirect object.

1. The most common way to introduce an indirect object is following the pattern of the first sentence.

Subject + Transitive Verb + Indirect Object + Direct Object.

2. The other way is also the pattern of the 2nd sentence you posted.

Subject + Transitive Verb + Indirect Object + to/for + Object of the preposition (which is also the indirect object)

**NOTE**: Sometimes, the indirect object will follow a preposition like to or for.

Comment: When it follows a preposition, it is a prepositional object, not a direct object or indirect object.

Comment: https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/indirect_object.htm